# I can't take input of sentence by using cin.get(str,100)

Tags: c++, string, input

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char str[100];
  int n;
cin>>n;
  std::cin.get(str, 100);
  
  cout <<str;
  return 0;
}
```

when i use cin.get() at first it works but it is not working if i use it after taking some inpute

Comment: That question is about `std::getline`, but both this and `std::cin.get()` are examples of unformatted stream extraction, while `std::cin >>` is formatted stream extraction. Using unformatted extraction after formatted one requires certain steps to clear the buffer from lingering newlines/whitespaces.

Comment: Please specify the input, actual output and the expected output of your program. It is unclear what you are trying to do.